# Google cloud storage uploads 0 Bytes Node.js

Tags: node.js, upload, google-cloud-storage, createwritestream

I am using Google-Cloud-Storage.  This code will save an object in the bucket but it is just empty.  It shows a size of 0 Bytes

```
req.file = req.files.file;
const bucketName = req.body.bucketName || DEFAULT_BUCKET_NAME;
const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);
const gcsFileName = `${Date.now()}-${req.file.name}`;
const file = bucket.file(gcsFileName);
const stream = file.createWriteStream({
  // resumable: false, 
  // gzip: true,
  metadata: {
      contentType: req.file.mimetype,
    },
});

stream.on('error', (err) => {
  req.file.cloudStorageError = err;
    next(err)
});
stream.on('finish', () => {
    console.log('image uploaded succesfully')
    req.file.cloudStorageObject = gcsFileName;
  return file.makePublic()
    .then(() => {
      req.file.gcsUrl = gcsHelpers.getPublicUrl(bucketName, gcsFileName);
      next()
    });
});

stream.end(req.files.file.buffer);
```

Comment: How confident are you that req.files.file.buffer contains anything?  Maybe try a trivial sample where you just write a constant string.

Comment: thanks Kolban, that was it.  I needed to return req.files.file.data which contained the buffer.

Answer (score 7):

Working through the comments, it was found that the issue was that the write to GCS wasn't being passed the expected data which resulted in nothing being written.  In the original code, we had:

```
stream.end(req.files.file.buffer);
```

which would have closed the file after writing the data in the variable.  However, the variable's identity wasn't correct and what should have been coded was:

```
stream.end(req.files.file.data);
```